# Texture is deformed when drawing to screen

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to draw a HUD on the screen. I currently have it to display hearts depending on the Player's health. The images are transparent, and I have enabled
`glEnable(GL_BLEND);`
and
`glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

Code:

```
public void drawHUD() {
    for(int i = 1; i <= p.getHealth(); i++) {
        heart.bind();
        float y = 30;
        float x = 35 * i;
        glPushMatrix();
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex2f(x, y);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex2f(x + w.block_size, y);
            glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex2f(x + w.block_size, y + w.block_size);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex2f(x, y + w.block_size);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

Heart:

[image]

When its drawn:

[image]

(Texture is at 32x32)

Comment: 2nd & 4th texture coordinates are identical.

Comment: @BrettHale I always screw up, and it's always right in front of me... Thanks.